# Rename an Ada package

Tags: ada

Is it possible to have a different file name for a package than its actual name? I have tried to use the pragmas below but get errors like "pragma source_file_name_project argument has incorrect identifier"

```
package Parent_With_Very_Long_Name is end Parent_with_Very_Long_Name;
...
package Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child is
    pragma Source_File_Name_Project("parent-child.ads");
end Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child;
```

- [Source_File_Name_Project](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Source_005fFile_005fName_005fProject.html#Pragma-Source_005fFile_005fName_005fProject)
- [Source_File_Name](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Source_005fFile_005fName.html)

Comment: Both of those links tell you *not* to use `Source_File_Name_Project`. That said - I assure you that `Source_File_Name` works, but if you want us to help you you **must** show us what you actually wrote, and what file you wrote it in. And, for preference, the actual error message you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual storage of Ada source text is technically an implementation detail of the compiler.

Looking at the file names your compiler expects, I would guess that you are using GNAT (GCC-Ada).  GNAT allows you to override the default naming scheme in project files:

```
project Short_File_Names is
   package Naming is
      for Specification ("Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child")
        use "parent-child.ads";
   end Naming;
end Short_File_Names;
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `pragma Source_File_Name` says the syntax is

```
 pragma Source_File_Name (
   [Unit_Name   =>] unit_NAME,
   Spec_File_Name =>  STRING_LITERAL,
   [Index => INTEGER_LITERAL]);

 pragma Source_File_Name (
   [Unit_Name   =>] unit_NAME,
   Body_File_Name =>  STRING_LITERAL,
   [Index => INTEGER_LITERAL]);
```

so the reason the compiler is complaining is that you've used incorrect syntax. Using the correct syntax, that would be

```
package Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child is
   pragma Source_File_Name 
     (Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child, Spec_File_Name => "parent-child.ads");
end Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child;
```

but the compiler now says

```
parent-child.ads:2:01: incorrect placement for configuration pragma "Source_File_Name"
```

The proper placement for this configuration pragma is before the unit:

```
pragma Source_File_Name 
  (Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child, Spec_File_Name => "parent-child.ads");
package Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child is
end Parent_With_Very_Long_Name.Child;
```

which is all very well, but how are other units going to know this? (GNAT has a source-based compilation model). One answer is to put the pragma in a configuration file, `gnat.adc` by default. A better answer is to use GNAT project files and `package Naming`, as suggested by Jacob Sparre Andersen.

Comment: Yes, I am getting different errors now related to the units not knowing how to include each other. From what you describe a configuration file or additions to the project file are needed to work around this?

Errors:
"file parent-child.ads does not contain expected unit. Expected unit parent.child, found unit Parent_with_Very_Long_Name.Child"

Comment: I don't understand why you got that particular error; I just compiled the source as in the answer without error. And yes, you need a configuration file or a project file.